# How to make a Select list with Values in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

How can I, using the `options` binding in Knockout and an array of objects, generate a list of options with a `value` attribute that can be used like a normal select list in a form?

Some example data...

```
[
    { "Id": "0", "Title": "Red", "Desc": "Some text.." },
    { "Id": "1", "Title": "Green", "Desc": "Other text.." },
    { "Id": "2", "Title": "Blue", "Desc": "More text.." }
]
```

The desired output would look like this...

```
<select name="color">
    <option value="0">Red</option>
    <option value="1">Green</option>
    <option value="2">Blue</option>
</select>
```

As seen below, and in my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LrBL/1/), I also want to show a description in a separate area. It seems like this should all be very easy to accomplish but I can't figure out how to get that ID value into the option's `value` attribute.

My HTML...

```
<select data-bind="options: colors,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
                   optionsValue: 'Title',
                   value: selectedColor"></select>

<hr>

<h3>Description</h3>
<div data-bind="text: selectedColor()"></div>
```

My JavaScript...

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedColor = ko.observable();

    self.colors = ko.observableArray([
        { "Id": "0", "Title": "Red", "Desc": "Some text.." },
        { "Id": "1", "Title": "Green", "Desc": "Other text.." },
        { "Id": "2", "Title": "Blue", "Desc": "More text.." }
    ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I've tried things like...

```
self.description = ko.observable(self.selectedColor().Desc);
```

...but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change you data-bind from `optionsValue` to `optionsText` on the select. Then the value of selectedColor will be the entire object. In your div, you would data-bind to `selectedColor().Desc`

```
<select data-bind="options: colors,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
                   optionsText: 'Title',
                   value: selectedColor"></select>

<hr>

<h3>Description</h3>
<div data-bind="text: selectedColor().Desc"></div>
```

Now, if you absolutely need the `select` to have the value be the ID, then you can have one property to hold the ID, and another computed property to get the selected color object. like in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9wZFk/

Notice that I changed some of the bindings as well.

Basically renamed your existing property and added another:

```
self.selectedColorId = ko.observable();
self.selectedColor = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.colors()[self.selectedColorId()];
});
```

Comment: Ah! It was the `optionsText` part that I was missing. When I only set the `optionsValue` both the text and value were being set but when I set both of these, e.g. `optionsText: 'Title'` and `optionsValue: 'Id'` then I get the kind of select list I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!